# Laravel 5.1 Command empty table

Tags: laravel, command, eloquent, laravel-artisan

I'm using a command to add products from an API to my database using the following code

```
class UpdateCatalog extends Command {

    protected $name = 'catalog:update';
    protected $description = 'Command description.';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fire()
    {

        $products = Api::productsGetProducts();

        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            $detail = Api::productsGetProduct($product['id']);
            $product = new Product();
            $product->id = $detail->getId();
            $product->external_id = $detail->getExternalId();
            $product->name = $detail->getName();
            $product->description = $detail->getDescription();
            $product->thumbnail = $detail->getThumbnail();
            $product->price = $detail->getPrices()[0]['price_excl_vat'];
            $product->vat = $detail->getVat();
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

> Now I'm wondering if it's possible to empty the table prior to filling it again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to empty your `Product` database table?

This can be done with [truncate](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#deletes) like this:

`Product::truncate();`

Note: This will remove all rows and reset the auto-incrementing ID to zero

Comment: Aha thank you! I must have missed this in the documentation.

Comment: My ID kept going up after using that.